# php path error in imagejpeg()

Tags: php, image, path, warnings

when i use imagejpeg() it works fine in local while giving error on live

here is the warning message

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'http://test.ourserv.com/Optfolder/cmp_dd5ac79bcf/20131027_185925.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home3/test/public_html/server/Optfolder/image_re.php on line 36
```

i had same error with opendir() but when i write path like this it resolved but when i use even this kind of path instead of http it does not work with imagejpeg() 
what is the path should i use,why path work locally fine and not on live server in php??

```
 opendir('/home3/test/public_html/server/Optfolder/upload/upload');
```

Comment: try providing permission to the folder

Comment: You must write to file. `http://test.ourserv.com/...` is definitely not a filename.

Comment: i set permission 777 but still it shows error

Comment: Are you trying to write to a URL‽ `imagejpeg($im, 'http://...')`? That's not going to work.

Comment: @deceze Absolutely. That's what he does.

Comment: that what should i use? why its working fine locally?

Comment: @vishal Show us, how you call the function locally and on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use path like this
this will help you

```
 $abs_dir=dirname(__FILE__);
```